# "invalid repository/tag reference format" error when tagging an docker image

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to create an image tag using the below command but I am getting an error:

```
$ docker tag s1-env-project-data-explorer-ui:latest 111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/s1-env-project-common:s1-env-project-data-explorer-ui:latest

Error parsing reference: "111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/s1-env-project-common:s1-env-project-data-explorer-ui:latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A docker tag cannot have a `:` in it. From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description):

> The tag must be valid ASCII and can contain lowercase and uppercase letters, digits, underscores, periods, and hyphens.

so the following is invalid:

> 111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/s1-env-project-common:s1-env-project-data-explorer-ui:latest

As per your comment, if you are working with two different components, you should certainly have two different ECR repositories.

Answer (score 0):

please consider below format

```
docker tag <repo_name>:<tag_name> <account_id>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<repo_name>:<tag_name>
```

for example:

```
docker tag repo1:first_tag 111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/repo1:first_tag
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however, it didn't directly help my issue

Comment: Sure no worries , glad @paolo was able to point out the issue.